# How can an AWS CodeBuild job see which files have changed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to set up an AWS CodeBuild project to run tests to validate PRs and commits on a GitHub repository.

Because of the nature of the repo (a monorepo combining several ML models):

- I need to restrict down to only run tests associated with files changed in the PR/commit to keep time+cost under control, but
- The tests will typically require reference to other un-changed files in the repo: So can't just *only* pull changed files through to the build container.

How can a running CodeBuild build triggered by a GitHub PR (as per the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-github-pull-request.html)) 'see' which files are changed by the PR to selectively execute tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git diff --name-only $$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION $$CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT`

Where **$CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT** is the commit id of the previous commit. And **$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION** is the commit id of the actual one.

Inside a build phase you can check the change with:

```
- |
    if [ "$(git diff --name-only $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION $CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT | grep -e <filde_path>)" != "" ]; then
      #your code;
    fi
```

Comment: Belated thanks! I think I ended up finding that different repo sources (CodeCommit, GitHub, etc) and trigger types (direct, via CodePipeline, etc) could reflect differently in the various env vars CodeBuild sets? For GitHub e.g. pull requests could also refer to their [compare API](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/viewing-and-comparing-commits/comparing-commits)

Comment: We use it with a GitHub repo, and works. I don't know if it works for other repos like Bitbucket.

Answer (score 2):

In your `buildspec` file you can perform `shell` commands, I think you can use some `git` commands there and `echo` the result, so you can see them as logs during the build.